# Shellscript Newbie - Issue with Wildcards & Arguments in a Script

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

As the title suggests I'm just starting out with shellscript so don't really know much about it!

My question is this - why does the following wildcard work in bash

```
    mv *.txt /root/Dustbin
```

But my shellscript file only moves one .txt file and not all? I install the script and call it as follows

```
del *.txt
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#sh scriptname del

mv -u $1 /root/Dustbin

#END OF SCRIPT
```

Hope my question makes sense

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Because `$1` only references one file.  Try `mv "$@" /root/Dustbin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` is the first argument of the script. So even if there are multiple files matching `*.txt`, only the first one will be moved.
If you want to move all of them, use `"$@"` instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv -u "$@" /root/Dustbin
```

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it